# Is the "pending" part of ✩-expandable map functions guaranteed to be brace-balanced?

Tags: expansion

Let's say, for some "academical" purpose, I want to write some macro that is f-type expandable (or something similar), and want to use one of the expl3's map functions inside it, and I assume `\expanded` is not available.

So I do the following...

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \weird #1 #2 \mark #3 {
    #2 \mark {#3 #1,}
}

%\pretty:o
\tl_show:o
{ \exp:w \int_step_function:nN {10} \weird \expandafter \exp_end: \use_none:n \mark {} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Basically, for each value `#1` the function `weird` received as argument, it searches forward in the input stream for the `{}` (`#3`), append `#1,` to it, then restore the input stream state.

The end result is `{1, 2, 3, …, 10}`. <sub>(roughly speaking.)</sub>

In the current LaTeX/expl3 version it does work, but I observe that if the "context" part (`#2`) is not brace-balanced it will fail.

Question: Is this guaranteed to work? (since the `\__exp` family of functions for simulating `\expanded` on engines that doesn't have it does assume that brace balance is not changed so it's probably safe...?)

Alternatively: is there any way to use one of the ✩-expandable functions in an f-like expansion environment that is guaranteed to work? <sub>I say "f-like" here because it's not really f-type expansion without the `\exp_end_continue_f:` token, but it makes no difference here.</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137360/discussion-on-question-by-user202729-is-the-pending-part-of--expandable-map-f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, nothing using 'brace tricks' is set up using `f`-type expansion. Rather, they are all cases where 'normal' tokens are placed into the input stream as they are 'decided on'. Thus one can make the assumption you wish to.

---

Note that `\expanded` is nowadays required by LaTeX, and at some stage soon will be by `expl3`. At that point, we are very likely to revisit expansion and convert all functions which are `x`-type expandable to  be always `f`-type (by using `\expanded`): that will mean that life gets a lot less complex.

Comment: did you mean f or e ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I means `f` - currently not everything that is `x`-type expandable is `f`-type, but with `\expanded` one can arrange that all the `x`type cases are 'one shots' so work in an `f`-type context